# How to avoid model's data being changed by redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stateless

My `home_controller.rb` looks likes like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @post_a = Post.where(title: 'a').sample
    @post_b = Post.where(title: 'b').sample
  end
```

And `index.html.erb` is like this:

```
<div>
   <%= @post_a.title %>
   <%= @post_b.title %>
</div>
```

When the page is refreshed, `@post_a.title` and `@post_b.title` are changed.

Is there any way to prevent data from being changed by refresh or redirect?

Comment: You are picking up random records by using `sample`, what do you except.

Answer (score 0):

The variables hold the value you assign to them. As you are taking a random record (using `sample`), the result of the query is a random record fetched from the database, therefore the value of those 2 variables is sort of *random*.

If you want a predictable record to be assigned to `@post_a` and `@post_b`, then you need to update the query to fetch the record you want.

For example, fetch by ID:

```
@post_a = Post.find(1)
```

Comment: Assuming what you mean by "[t]hey" in "They are not changed" to be `@post_a` and `@post_b`, they are indeed changing across requests (including redirects), contrary to what you wrote. And that is the whole point of this question. This answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: Yes, I was meaning the variables. I was actually unclear in the response, I mean the content of the records did not change, what changed was the value assigned to the variables as a random record was fetched.

Answer (score 0):

It is a basic property of RESTful, hence state-less, systems like those created by Rails that a response to a request cannot directly access what is done in another response. Everything that is to be accessed beyond responses have to be saved somewhere, usually databases.

In order to access from the second response the values of the variables you have set in the first response, the standard way is to save information in `session`. You can perhaps read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage).

Given that you are using redirect, another way is to pass the values as parameters to the path helper method when you call the redirect. Instead of doing:

```
redirect_to foo_bar_path
```

you can do:

```
redirect_to foo_bar_path(post_a_id: @post_a.id, post_b_id: @post_b.id)
```

and then in the controller action at the destination of redirect, you can access the ids of `@post_a` and `post_b` as `params[:post_a_id]` and `params[:post_b_id]`.